# Get all posts from a user with their category's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

### The Situation

I'm currently working on a Blog-system and I'm stuck at trying to get all posts with their category's made by a particular user.

The Query only shows the first post in the database, no madder how many posts a user has. Also, the generated category-output is wrong.

### Database

Here are the SQL-commands to create the three required tables.

#### Post

```
create table Post(
    headline varchar(100),
    date datetime,
    content text,
    author int unsigned,
    public tinyint,
    type int,
    ID serial,
    Primary Key (ID),
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`author` is the ID of the user who created the post, `public` determines if the post can be read from everyone or is just a draft and `type` determines if it's a blog-post (`0`) or something else.

#### Category

```
create table Kategorie(
    name varchar(30),
    short varchar(200),
    ID serial,
    Primary Key (name)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Post_Kategorie

```
create table Post_Kategorie(
    post_ID bigint unsigned,
    kategorie_ID bigint unsigned,
    Primary Key (post_ID, kategorie_ID),
    Foreign Key (post_ID) references Post(ID),
    Foreign Key (kategorie_ID) references Kategorie(ID)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### The Query

This is the query I currently have, but as mentioned above, it doesn't work like I want it to.

```
SELECT Post.headline, Post.date, 
 CONCAT(
  "[", GROUP_CONCAT('{"name":"',Kategorie.name,'","id":',Kategorie.ID,'}'), "]"
 ) as "categorys"
FROM Post, Kategorie, Post_Kategorie
WHERE Post.author = 1
AND(
  Post.public = 1
  AND Post.type = 0
)AND(
  Post_Kategorie.post_ID = Post.ID
  AND Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID = Kategorie.ID
)
```

Since one post can have multiple category's, the query generates JSON which is then decoded to an object in PHP. This was the easies way to archive this, thought.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing this in the end:

```
GROUP BY Post.headline, Post.date
```

**Update**

Also, you noticed that when a post has no categories, it does not appear. The problem is that you are performing `JOIN` via `WHERE` clause. When you do that, your join will always behave as an `INNER JOIN`.

In order to have Posts always, you need to `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Post.headline, Post.date, 
 CONCAT(
  "[", GROUP_CONCAT('{"name":"',Kategorie.name,'","id":',Kategorie.ID,'}'), "]"
 ) as "categorys"
FROM Post 
  LEFT JOIN Post_Kategorie 
    ON Post.ID = Post_Kategorie.post_ID
  LEFT JOIN Kategorie 
    ON Post_Kategorie.kategorie_ID = Kategorie.ID
WHERE Post.author = 1
AND Post.public = 1
AND Post.type = 0
GROUP BY Post.headline, Post.date
```

Comment: Okay, this works. But another thing: When a Post has no category, it's not in the listed posts. How would I solve this?

Comment: Well, that would be another question.. But I will update my answer to accommodate that

Comment: In my course we didn't cover that yet. I'll take a look at it, thank you.